# Odoo, Condition in record tag

Tags: xml, odoo

i have a question about odoo or specific about record tag on xml odoo. Can i give a condition for record tag. example like this :

```
    <record id="A" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Record A</field>
    </record>

    <record id="B" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Record B</field>
    </record>
```

I have a two record's and i want give a condition like, if record id=A is **True**, i want record id=B following the record id=A, become **True**.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Because wat odoo do is convering the record tag to an insert query or update query 
the id returned by the insertion is mapped with the attribute id `(id="A")` this why we call it xml-id. and if you want to get the id in database we do this for example: `self.env.ref('xml_id_here')`

But if you want complicated things like that what you should do is use python code using the function tag:

```xml
   <function model="model.name" name="method_name" />
```

in your model:

```py
  class ModelName(models.Model):
        _name = 'model.name'
        ....
        ....
        @api.model
        def method_name(self):
            # and here you can use the power of python to do 
            # anything you want
```